Android app to capture video and stream it over rtsp url
Can anyone send me the link to the git repo of an android app which basically captures the video through android camera via app and generates a rtsp url on the screen in a textview so that the url can be entered in the vlc media player to stream the video captured through app. Live streaming!
Tried searching it for a long time. I am finding the repos where app itself is streaming the video. But not finding the repo which can send the video for streaming over rtsp url.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
